# Is it possible to get data for a 'analytics group' of videos from YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: python, youtube, google-analytics, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I am trying to retrieve data for videos for an Analytics group in a YouTube channel.

In the Analytics interface, this is done by selecting the 'Groups' drop down near the top of the page and then selecting 'Browse all groups'; this then allows the user to select a particular group by clicking on its name. The reports now show data just for videos in the selected group. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Is this possible via the YouTube Analytics API? I was expecting it to be possible via a 'dimensions' parameter but couldn't find anything suitable.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was recently added to the Analytics API on February the 25th 2015.

> The API now supports the ability to create and manage YouTube Analytics groups as well as the ability to retrieve report data for those groups.

See here for further reading https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/groups